# Function from $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ into $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Define

$$g: \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$

be given via

$$x \mapsto x - \frac{1}{x}$$

is $g$ $1-1$ and onto? I wanna say its not onto cause you never hit $1$? and its certainly onto as if $x \neq y$, then

$$x- \frac{1}{x} \neq y - \frac{1}{y}$$

Furthermore, if $I$ is some finite closed and bounded interval in $(0,\infty)$, show

$$\int_\Bbb{R} f(g(x))dx = \int_\Bbb{R} f(x) dx$$

where $f$ is the characteristic function on $I$. Isn't the RHS just $m(I)$? and for the LHS I'm plugging in $g$ into the characteristic on $I$? does this still hold if $I \subset (-\infty,0)$?

Comment: What makes you say that you never hit $1$?

Comment: what real number minus 1/itself equals $1$?? @BenGrossmann

Comment: The Golden Ratio and its conjugate i.e $\frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Anyway this just appears like you’re trying to prove a special case of Glasser’s master theorem.

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath': You can answer your question for yourself by solving the quadratic equation $x^2-1=x$.

Comment: The statement from which you conclude it is onto in fact would show it is one-to-one (as long as you prove it).

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' Ultimately, you should find that $g$ is in fact onto, but not one-to-one.

Comment: It isn't one-to-one since both $-1,\ +1$ map to $0.$

Comment: For onto, can I take some $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ and show there exists a nonzero $x \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x^2-1=x \alpha$?

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' To your last comment/question: Yes, if you show that you have shown it is onto.

Comment: @coffeemath can I show this using the quadratic formula ? I end up with $x = \frac{\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2+4}}{2}$ which is in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @HossienS'MyMathYourMath' Yes. That's what Bens answer does, since the thing under the square root symbol is the "discriminant", and in your notation it is $\alpha^2+4$ which is positive for any $\alpha$ so the real square root exists. [He used $y$ where you put $\alpha$ but that's just notation choice.

Comment: @KStarGamer hey man ! Thanks for that, I hadn't heard of it before!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that the function is onto, consider the equation
$$
y = g(x) = x - \frac 1x.
$$
We wish to show that for any $y \in \Bbb R$, this equation has a solution for $x$. Rearrange it to obtain the quadratic equation
$$
x^2 - yx - 1 = 0.
$$
The discriminant of this equation is given by
$$
\Delta = (-y)^2 - 4(1)(-1) = y^2 + 4 > 0,
$$
which means that this equation will have two solutions for all $y \in \Bbb R$. The fact that this equation has two solutions for at least one value (and in fact, for all values) of $y$  means that $g$ is not one-to-one.

However, closer analysis allows us to deduce that the two solutions $x = \frac{y \pm \sqrt{y^2 + 4}}{2}$ will necessarily be of opposite sign, which means that the restrictions of $g$ to both $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ are one-to-one and onto. It can also be shown that both restrictions are increasing (since both are the sum of the increasing functions $x\mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto -1/x$).

For the second half of the question: indeed, the RHS is simply the measure of the interval $I$. The left hand side, on the other hand, is the measure of the set $S = \{x \in \Bbb R: g(x) \in I\} = g^{-1}(I)$.

Let $g_-$ denote the restriction of $g$ to $(-\infty,0)$ and $g_+$ the restriction to $(0,\infty)$. We can write $g^{-1}(I) = g_+^{-1}(I) \cup g_-^{-1}(I)$. Because $g_\pm$ are continuous, they map intervals to intervals. If $I = (a,b)$ for $0<a\leq b$, then we can use the quadratic formula to find that
$$
\begin{align}
m(g_+^{-1}(I)) &= \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2} - \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}
\\&= \frac 12 (b-a) + \left[ \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}\right].
\end{align}
$$
Similarly,
$$
m(g_-^{-1}(I)) = \frac 12 (b-a) - \left[ \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + 4}}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{a^2 + 4}}{2}\right].
$$
If we add up the measures of these disjoint intervals, we end up with the desired result that $m(g^{-1}(I)) = b-a = m(I)$.

By tracing through the same steps, we can see that the same result applies for $I \subset (-\infty,0)$.